# How to filter product collection by attribute's admin option values?

Tags: magento-1.7, module, attributes, collection, programming

I am currently developing a product configurator. I am submitting a form which sends the admin option values of my custom attributes via POST to a controller action. If I use the current store's attribute option labels all is working just fine, the product collection is filtered correctly and a simple product which is associated to a configurable product is returned. 
Sadly I am using the admin values for form and URL generation because the default swedish store values contain too many special characters.

So my question is: how do I get the right product from my collection when using the admin option values or more specific, how do I get the admin option value's ID like using this for the default store's values:

```
$id = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
                                    ->getAttribute($key)
                                    ->getSource()
                                    ->getOptionId($value);
```

I already tried filtering by addStoreFilter(0), but that didn't work either. I already read that it could have something to do with flat tables being used in default store but not for admin, but I am rather unexperienced with Magento, so I don't really understand the difference using flat tables and what that really means.

Here is my last question concerning the filtering for reference:
[addFieldToFilter doesn't return the right product for selected attribute values](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5920/addfieldtofilter-doesnt-return-the-right-product-for-selected-attribute-values)

Here is my getProduct() function:

```
public function getProduct($attributes)
    {

        Mage::Log($attributes);

        $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

        //Get Product Collection
        $collection = $productModel->getCollection()


        //Filter for Selected Product
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('status');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('doorconfig_enable');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('doorconfig_enable',array('eq' => 1));

        foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) 
        {
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect($key);

            $id = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
                                    ->getAttribute($key)
                                    ->getSource()
                                    ->getOptionId($value);

            $collection->addAttributeToFilter($key,
                array(
                        'eq' => $id
                     )
            );

        }

        $selection = $collection->getSelect()->__toString();

        Mage::Log($selection);

        Mage::log($collection->getSize(),null,'custom.log');

        $product = $collection->getFirstItem();

        return $product;

    }
```

Comment: Where are you running the query? (admin app, or frontend app?)

Comment: I am using the app/design/frontend folder and my configurator is running on the homepage, which should mean the code is running on the frontend app I guess :)

Comment: Yes, you're in the frontend app (Some collections behave differently depending on where they are)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like all of Magento, the answer's in the source — all you need to do is go digging (or hop to then end of this post).

First, find the class for the attribute source

```
$source = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
->getAttribute('color')
->getSource();        
var_dump(get_class($source));
exit;
```

In modern versions of Magento, this should point to the class `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Table`, which is located at

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Table.php
class Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Table extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract
{
    //...
}
```

Next, we'll look for the definition of the `getOptionId` method on this class and/or it's parent classes.  We'll find it in the `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract` class

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Abstract.php
public function getOptionId($value)
{
    foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
        if (strcasecmp($option['label'], $value)==0 || $option['value'] == $value) {
            return $option['value'];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Examining this method, we can see if works by `foreach`ing over a list of options from the `getAllOptions` method.  So let's look at this method's definition.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Table.php
public function getAllOptions($withEmpty = true, $defaultValues = false)
{
    $storeId = $this->getAttribute()->getStoreId();
    if (!is_array($this->_options)) {
        $this->_options = array();
    }
    if (!is_array($this->_optionsDefault)) {
        $this->_optionsDefault = array();
    }
    if (!isset($this->_options[$storeId])) {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
            ->setPositionOrder('asc')
            ->setAttributeFilter($this->getAttribute()->getId())
            ->setStoreFilter($this->getAttribute()->getStoreId())
            ->load();
        $this->_options[$storeId]        = $collection->toOptionArray();
        $this->_optionsDefault[$storeId] = $collection->toOptionArray('default_value');
    }
    $options = ($defaultValues ? $this->_optionsDefault[$storeId] : $this->_options[$storeId]);
    if ($withEmpty) {
        array_unshift($options, array('label' => '', 'value' => ''));
    }

    return $options;
}
```

Ah ha!  Now we're on to something. This appears to be the method that loads all the option information.  Specifically, we're interested in

```
$storeId = $this->getAttribute()->getStoreId();
```

So, Magento gets the store ID for the options to load **from the attribute**.  This means you should be able to do something like the following (replacing `color` and `red` with your own variables, of course)

```
    //get the attribute
    $attribute = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
    ->getAttribute('color');

    //set the store id on the attribute
    $attribute->setStoreId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

    //get the source
    $source = $attribute->getSource();

    //get the id
    $id = $source->getOptionId('red');
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, just got time to continue the project :) Thank you so much for this more than detailed answer! This works like a charm and I even understand where to look next time!